# Adding data to App's vue file breaks imported component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm a beginner in vue and I'm trying to add data to my vue App file, but when I add data() the imported component it doesn't render.

I wanted to add links' label and url as an object, but it just breaks the whole code.

App file

```
<script>
import LinkButton from './components/LinkButton.vue'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      count: 1
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <h1>My landing site</h1>

  <LinkButton 
    linkUrl="#"
    linkText="Strava"
  />
  <LinkButton 
    linkUrl="#"
    linkText="Instagram"
  />
</template>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Imported component

```
<script> export default {
    props: {
        linkUrl: String,
        linkText: String
        
    },
    data() {
        return {
        }
    }
}

</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <a :href="linkUrl">{{ linkText }}</a>
    </div>
</template>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're learning Vue 3, it's probably best to learn the newest features and functionality which would mean learning Composition API.  You're using the older Options API from Vue 2.  You can learn the differences between the two [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles).  Having said that, assuming you have your reasons for using Options API, the key thing to know after importing a component is you also have to register it with the `components` option:

```js
<script>
import LinkButton from './LinkButton.vue';

export default {
  components: { LinkButton },
  data() {
    return {
      count: 1
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[Documentation source](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/registration.html#local-registration) (make sure to switch the toggle in the top-left from Composition to Options)